# Laravel 4: Passing variable in route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to do route controller and in my route file it looks something like this:

```
Route::get('/data', 'ProcessController@data');
Route::get('/data2', 'ProcessController@data2');
Route::get('/data3', 'ProcessController@data3');
Route::get('/data4', 'ProcessController@data4');
```

As you can see the pattern there. How can I make everything into one line, so that I don't need to repeatedly assigning the route?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any pattern here, data1 is not the same as data2 , the Pattern route should share the same base rout like : admin/index,admin/user,admin/help or admin/anything, here the pattern is admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a pattern, but you won't be able to assing different routes to differents controllers actions in one single line, but you can add this one as your **last route**, because this route will catch everything and your other routes may not hit:

```
Route::get('/{data}', 'ProcessController@process');
```

And in your controller:

```
<?php

class ProcessController extends Controller {

    public function process($data)
    {
        $this->{$data}(); // execute your method
    }

    public function data() {}
    public function data1() {}
    public function data2() {}
    public function data3() {}

}
```

This is untested code and you'll need much more code than that, because you'll also need to test if the method exists in your controller and, if it doesn't, redirects your user to the another one.